# Determining Foreground Color of Text in Google Slides When the Text Uses Multiple Foreground Colors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I am creating a script that will allow me to change the text foreground color within different items of a Google Slide.  I am able to change the text foreground color if all of the text within the element use the same color.  The following will change the text colored #000000 to #22AA22.

```
function changeTextColors(){
  var elements = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection().getCurrentPage().getPageElements();
  elements.forEach(element => {
    var type = element.getPageElementType();
    if (type == 'SHAPE') {
      var text = element.asShape().getText().asString();
      var textStyle = element.asShape().getText().getTextStyle();
      if(textStyle.getForegroundColor() !== null &&
      textStyle.getForegroundColor().getColorType().toString() !== 'THEME') {
        if (textStyle.hasLink() !== null  &&
        textStyle.getForegroundColor().asRgbColor().asHexString() == '#000000' && text.trim() != '') {
          textStyle.setForegroundColor('#22AA22');
        };
      };
    };
  });
}
```

However, when multiple foreground colors are used within the same element, the foreground color returned for `element.asShape().getText().getTextStyle().getForegroundColor()` is null.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#getforegroundcolor

How can I determine the Foreground Color of each character within the shape so that I can change the color by character?

Comment: In order to correctly understand `How can I determine the Foreground Color of each character within the shape so that I can change the color by character?`, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images?

Comment: An element that contains the text "Black Red Black" and the foreground color of each word would be Black-#000000 and Red-#FF0000, will give a result of null when getting the Foreground color.  I want to be able to change the words "Black" which have a Foreground color of #000000 to the foreground color of #22AA22 and keep the word Red at the Foreground color of #FF0000.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I thought that I could correctly understand your question. So, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to change the text foreground color from `#000000` to `#22AA22`.
- In your situation, there is a case that a part of the text is `#000000`.

In this case, when your showing script is modified, how about modifying it as follows?

#### Modified script 1:

In this pattern, your script is modified by separating the texts with and without a part of colored text.

```js
function changeTextColors() {
  const changeForegroundColor_ = (ts, text) => {
    if (ts.hasLink() !== null && ts.getForegroundColor().asRgbColor().asHexString() == '#000000' && text.trim() != '') {
      ts.setForegroundColor('#22AA22');
    };
  }

  var elements = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection().getCurrentPage().getPageElements();
  elements.forEach(element => {
    var type = element.getPageElementType();
    if (type == 'SHAPE') {
      var t = element.asShape().getText();
      var text = t.asString();
      var textStyle = element.asShape().getText().getTextStyle();
      if (textStyle.getForegroundColor() !== null && textStyle.getForegroundColor().getColorType().toString() !== 'THEME') {
        changeForegroundColor_(textStyle, text);
      } else {
        t.getRuns().forEach(r => changeForegroundColor_(r.getTextStyle(), text));
      }
    }
  });
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this pattern, your script is modified by `getRuns()`.

```js
function changeTextColors() {
  var elements = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection().getCurrentPage().getPageElements();
  elements.forEach(element => {
    var type = element.getPageElementType();
    if (type == SlidesApp.PageElementType.SHAPE) {
      var t = element.asShape().getText();
      t.getParagraphs().forEach(p => {
        var text = p.getRange().asString();
        p.getRange().getRuns().forEach(r => {
          var ts = r.getTextStyle();
          if (ts.getForegroundColor().getColorType() !== SlidesApp.ColorType.THEME && ts.hasLink() !== null && ts.getForegroundColor().asRgbColor().asHexString() == '#000000' && text.trim() != '') {
            ts.setForegroundColor('#22AA22');
          };
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, when a part of the text is `#000000`, the text of `#000000` is converted to `#22AA22`.

#### Reference:

- [getRuns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#getruns)

Comment: Thank you!  I missed the getRange and getRuns "options" when combing through Google's horribly designed support file.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
function changeTextColors(){
  var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var elements = slide.getSelection().getCurrentPage().getPageElements();

  elements.forEach(element => {
    var type = element.getPageElementType();
    if (type == 'SHAPE') {
      var textLength = element.asShape().getText().asString().length;
          for(i = 0; i < textLength;i++){
              try{
                  var textColor = element.asShape().getText().getRange(i,1 + i).getTextStyle().getForegroundColor().asRgbColor().asHexString();
                  console.log(textColor);
              }
              catch(error){
                  console.log(error);
              element.asShape().getText().getRange(i,1 + i).getTextStyle().setForegroundColor('#22AA22');
              }
          }
        };
    });
  }
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I really wish Google's information is better designed.  This was helpful!